# R: multiple Friedman tests

Tags: r, loops, statistics

A little problem when doing multiple times the same test.

I am using the friedman.test to test the variations of paired samples. The function itself poses no problem, I have the expected result for each column using the script :

```
friedman.test(Variable ~ Time | Patient, data=table1)
```

However I have several variables that have been measured for each patients (on several time points). I can do a test per variable using the script above, but I would like to do it sequentially and automatically on a chosen set of variables. I tried entering the variables I want to test in a vector or a list and using the vector/list as the "Variable" parameter, but it didn´t work.

Can someone point me in the right direction for a loop of this type ?

Thanks !
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `as.formula()` is the key to this. I will explain with a small example.

From the build-in warpbreaks dataset (see `?friedman.test`) :

```
wb <- aggregate(warpbreaks$breaks,
                by = list(w = warpbreaks$wool,
                          t = warpbreaks$tension),
                FUN = mean)

> friedman.test(x ~ w | t, data = wb)

    Friedman rank sum test

data:  x and w and t
Friedman chi-squared = 0.3333, df = 1, p-value = 0.5637
```

Now let's suppose for simplicity that we have 3 variables that we want to test in a loop instead of x:

(for this example I will use the x variable each time, because it is a demonstration)

```
myvariables <- c('x','x','x')  #this is your vector with all of the variables you will use

for ( i in myvariables) {  #and this block is the loop
  formula_text <- sprintf('%s ~ w | t', i) #writes the formula as text
  a <- as.formula(formula_text) #converts text to formula
  print(friedman.test(a, data = wb)) #runs as wanted!
}
```

Output from above loop:

```
    Friedman rank sum test

data:  x and w and t
Friedman chi-squared = 0.3333, df = 1, p-value = 0.5637


    Friedman rank sum test

data:  x and w and t
Friedman chi-squared = 0.3333, df = 1, p-value = 0.5637


    Friedman rank sum test

data:  x and w and t
Friedman chi-squared = 0.3333, df = 1, p-value = 0.5637
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
varnames <- c("Variable1","Variable2")

for (curvar in varnames) {
print(curvar)
print(friedman.test(table1[,curvar] ~ Time | Patient, data=table1)
}
```