# How could I pass a character value as an offset argument into glm function?

Tags: r, glm

Suppose the dataset, *my_data*, looks like this

| Count | Covariate | offset_a | offset_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

while using *offset_a* as my offset, the below statement would work:

```
glm(my_formula, data = my_data, family = 'quasipoisson', offset = offset_a)
```

However, if I want to write a loop that passes *offset_a* and *offset_b* sequentially into *glm()*, I wouldn't be able to simply pass a character value into the offset argument. Like this:

```
offset_list <- c("offset_a", "offset_b")

for (k in offset_list){
  ...
  fit = glm(my_formula, data = my_data, family = 'quasipoisson', offset = k)
  ...
}
```

I tried applying noquote() to the offset, as

```
fit = glm(my_formula, data = my_data, family = 'quasipoisson', offset = noquote(k))
```

but it doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Furtherly,

if we have a character variable,

```
statement = "glm(my_formula, data = my_data, family = 'quasipoisson', offset = offset_a)"
```

Is there any way to pass variable, *statement*, into *glm()* directly and get the output successfully?

Much Appreciated!

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, all of which have been asked and answered on SO before. Read [tour], [ask], and [MCVE]

Comment: Hi @IRTFM, thanks for your comment! I am sorry if my question is duplicated. I asked because I have searched for a long time but still couldn't find the answer, probably due to unsuitable key words. I will keep working on it. :)

Comment: Narrow your question and search on the use of `as.formula` for converting from text to language objects in R. If you really did a diligent search then posting the search strategy and the results that were unhelpful would save time for your audience. (and the reason I'm not offering any hints on your second part is my desire to not encourage the posting of multi-part questions.

Comment: Nominations for  duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098644/how-to-create-a-loop-that-will-add-new-variables-to-a-pre-define-glm-model/33099169#33099169   .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318944/r-multiple-friedman-tests/27319403#27319403  I'm not able to revise my close action to use my dupe-hammer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to put the offset term directly into the formula with `reformulate`:

```r
resp_var <- "y"
form0 <- "var1 + var2 + var3*var4"
offset_list <- c("offset_a", "offset_b")
for (k in offset_list){
  ...
  form <- reformulate(response = resp_var,
                      c(form0, sprintf("offset(%s)", k)))
  fit <- glm(form, data = my_data, family = 'quasipoisson')
  ...
}
```

`offset = get(k)` would probably also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
offset_list <- c("offset_a", "offset_b")
fit <- list()
for (k in 1:length(offset_list)){
    fit[[k]] = glm(my_formula, data = my_data, family = 'quasipoisson',
    offset = get(offset_list[k]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found another solution myself.

According to the documentation of [glm](http://localhost:10336/library/stats/html/glm.html), the argument 'offset' could be

> NULL or a numeric vector of length equal to the number of cases.

So we could directly put the column 'offset_x' as vector into the offset argument.

Like this:

```
offset_list <- c("offset_a", "offset_b")

for (offset in offset_list){
  ...
  fit = glm(my_formula, data = my_data, family = 'quasipoisson', offset = my_data[[offset]])
  ...
}
```

I hope this helps.